# Uploading a file from mobile Andoid to force.com

Tags: force.com, mobilesdk, upload, file-storage

I want to upload an image that I get from my camera mobile to force.com, but i have an error that i  couldnt handle. Here is my code , if you have any ideas, please share. Thank you!

```
private void uploadImage() throws IOException{

        // send request
            RestRequest uploadImage= FileRequests.uploadFile(getOutputMediaFile(1), "PigePhotos", "Téléchargé via Android APP","image/jpeg");
        //RestRequest uploadImage= FileRequests.uploadFile(new File(""), "", "Téléchargé via Android APP","");

        Log.e("After restREsquet",""+uploadImage);
        Log.d("FILE PATH ",""+getOutputMediaFile(1));
        Log.d("FILE NAME ",""+titre);

        client.sendAsync(uploadImage, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {   
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
                try {
                    Log.d("FILE PATH ",""+getOutputMediaFile(1));
                    Log.d("FILE NAME ",""+titre);

                    Log.d("FICHIER BIEN INSERE","");
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // You might want to log the error or show it to the user
                    onError(e);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                // You might want to log the error or show it to the user
                Log.e("INSERTION FAILED","");}

        });
    }
```

**the log is the following:** 
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190): [70350] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.getContent(MultipartFormEntity.java:92)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.salesforce.androidsdk.auth.HttpAccess.execute(HttpAccess.java:301)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.salesforce.androidsdk.auth.HttpAccess.doPost(HttpAccess.java:200)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient$SalesforceHttpStack.performRequest(RestClient.java:547)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient$SalesforceHttpStack.performRequest(RestClient.java:469)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
05-12 15:41:22.934: E/Volley(15190):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)

Comment: See if this Stack Overflow post is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742844/cant-post-multipartentity-in-android-application. If not, I got a bunch of hits when I Googled using: "Exception: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()".

Comment: You can take a look here. This is an demo app I built for Android that used camera to upload images as attachments on a case. https://github.com/corycowgill/MobileFieldServiceApp